# Xamarin unable to bind ICommand in code/view model

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am developing a simple Xamarin.Forms app using a MVVM approach with VS 2017. Everything works as expected in UWP but my Android project does not execute the lines of code that get/set ICommand properties at all. I can set a breakpoint on the line that sets the property value, as well as the line before and the line after. I break on both lines before and after, but not on the line that sets the property.

Here is my view model code:

```
public LoginPageViewModel(INavigation navigation) : base() 
{
        Navigation = navigation;
        LoginButtonClicked = new Command(Login, () => true);
        PasswordHintButtonClicked = new Command(PasswordHint, () => true);
}
```

And my XAML.cs:

```
btnLogin.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty,  nameof(vm.LoginButtonClicked), BindingMode.OneWay);
btnPasswordHint.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, nameof(vm.PasswordHintButtonClicked), BindingMode.OneWay);
```

As I said, I can break on setting the Navigation property but not the command properties. If I move `Navigation = navigation` to the last line of the constructor I still break on it.

I've also tried:

```
private ICommand _loginButtonClicked;
public ICommand LoginButtonClicked
{
    get { return _loginButtonClicked ?? (_loginButtonClicked = new 
    Command(Login, () => true)); }
}
```

This should be pretty straightforward. Maybe I made a mistake configuring the Android emulator? I've been beating my head against this for a few days now, if anyone has seen something like this before I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone happens to come across this problem, in my case it was caused by missing `Preserve` attributes. I had added the attribute to all external assemblies but it was also required on my view models. For some reason the linker wasn't pulling in the entire class even though it was referenced in the .xaml.cs page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to set `BindingContext` before the `SetBinding` method.
For example, if the code looks like this:

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoginPageViewModel vm = new LoginPageViewModel();
            BindingContext = vm;
            btnLogin.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, nameof(vm.LoginButtonClicked), BindingMode.OneWay);
            btnPasswordHint.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, nameof(vm.PasswordHintButtonClicked), BindingMode.OneWay);                
        }
```

Then it can break on the line that sets the property and call the method.

You could refer to this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88187/custom-behavior-command-not-binding) for more information.